# Como dizer no Maven que um módulo depende de outro?

Tags: maven

Tenho dois módulos e cada um depende do outro.

Como dizer isso nas dependências no Maven?

Answer (score 3):

Dependência cíclica? Isso é falha de projeto, pois como você vai fazer para compilar o projeto A se ele depende do projeto B e vice-versa?
O correto neste caso é separar as funcionalidades em comum em um novo projeto C de modo que A e B dependerão apenas de C.

Comment: Talvez eu não possa alterar o código, é um projeto grande e legado

Comment: Então você tem um grande problema, pois na compilação sempre vai dar erro por falta da dependência...

Comment: conseguiram fazer compilar, mas por um "método alternativo", fizeram um 3º projeto e no linksource desse aponta para o source desses dois módulos, desse jeito conseguiram compilar e rodar, agora estou tentando fazer um refectory  e me deparei com essa situação

Answer (score 2):

Como você citou que não pode alterar a estrutura, vou dar três ideias para *contornar* a situação:

## Incluindo os fontes

Em um dos projetos inclua os fontes necessários do outro usando o [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html). Note que ele não terá uma dependência direta.

Após a compilação, você pode excluir as classes compiladas que não fazem parte deste projeto no [jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) ou no [war](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html).

O outro projeto pode depender do primeiro sem problemas, desde que respeitada a ordem de build. Ou então você pode aplicar essa solução para ambos os projetos.

## Incluindo as classes

A solução anterior pode ser implementada incluindo diretamente as classes compiladas de um projeto no `classpath` do outro. Isso pode ser feito, por exemplo, com o [Maven Antrun Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Note que nesta solução e na anterior, considera-se que os dois projetos estão disponíveis no sistema de arquivos local. Caso os projetos sejam compilados em um servidor, ainda é possível usar outro plugin para baixar os arquivos necessários do seu versionador de arquivos.

## Criando uma dependência *fake*

Com o projeto mais simples, crie manualmente um jar apenas com as classes e interfaces necessárias. Adicione esse jar em seu repositório local, no Artifactory ou Nexus da sua empresa.

Então faça o projeto mais complexo depender desse novo jar em [escopo `provided`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope), isto é, ele será usado em tempo de compilação mas não em execução.

Dessa forma, a compilação do projeto mais complexo ocorrerá sem problemas, já que pelo menos a "casca" das classes necessárias existe no `classpath`. E o projeto mais simples pode depender diretamente do projeto complexo, que já estará compilado.